# Azure CLI | list resources

Tags: azure-cli

Team,

I'm using the below query to list all the resources in my subscription.
But whereas resourcetype is coming as null. but all other parameters are coming fine.
Can someone help to suggest.

```
az resource  list --query "[].{resourceGroup:resourceGroup,resourcetype:resourcetype,name:name,location:location,env:tags.Environment,appname:tags.ApplicationName,appmaintainedby:tags.AppMaintainedBy,tcs_scope:tags.TCSCloudOps_Scope,costcenter:tags.BusinessUnit_CostCenter,hpnum:tags.HPNumber}" 

az resource  list --query "[].{resourceGroup:resourceGroup,resource-type:resource-type,name:name,location:location,env:tags.Environment,appname:tags.ApplicationName,appmaintainedby:tags.AppMaintainedBy,tcs_scope:tags.TCSCloudOps_Scope,costcenter:tags.BusinessUnit_CostCenter,hpnum:tags.HPNumber}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the "resourcetype:type" instead of "resourcetype:resourcetype" in the above command
refer the below screenshot for the reference.
[image]